# How do I put a number (or other text) in the left indent of a paragraph?

Tags: spacing, numbering

What I want is simply a number that appears to the left of the paragraph without changing anything else about it, as provided in the mockup image. Enumerate and other environments don't appear to be able to do this.[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `\paragraph{}` ?

Comment: It appears this command does what I need it to, setting the text in brackets off to the left of the indent. I also found the \normalfont command useful to remove the formatting it adds.

Comment: The `enumitem` package allows you to manipulate the position of the text after the label. Using this \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,itemindent=10pt]`` code the bullet is inline with the following text (or the text is aligned with the left margin). You don't have the formatting of the `\paragraph{}` to deal with and can set  the separation between text and item as well as the font used locally in the options box.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a not indented paragraph using `\noindent` and begin the new text of the paragraph with a `\makebox` of width `\parindent`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\parwithnumber}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \makebox[\parindent][l]{#1}\ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}
\parwithnumber{1.}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: using a not indented paragraph with makebox]

But, because I do not know the sense of your request, I do also not know, whether this is a good idea or not. Maybe using a `enumerate` environment and [package `enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) would be the better suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=*,itemindent=\parindent,align=left]
  \item\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: using enumerate and package enumitem]